# Logos and text at the top with a border around on each page of article

Tags: titles, article

I want to create the following (See the picture). After some horizontal and vertical margin, a border around the page is needed. Within the bordered region, two logos (shown with boxes) with a title sandwiched between the two followed by a rule should be there. At the bottom, a line needs to be drawn below which a reference text with page no is required (kind of footer). This has to be on every page of the article. The content will come in the remaining white space.[image]

Comment: Mostly you are talking fancy headers or footers, so fancyhdr could do most of it.  However, the border will require something like tikz, so I would use \AddToHook and tikzpagenodes instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need the help of `fancyhdr` for the header and footer plus `tikz` for the framing of the page. `atbegshi` will frame the first and  subsequent pages.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=4cm, right=4cm, headheight=1.5cm]{geometry}   
\usepackage{atbegshi}   
\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{\borders}}
\AtBeginShipoutFirst{\borders}

\pagestyle{fancy}{%
\fancyhead[L,R,C]{}
\fancyfoot[L,R,C]{}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[height=0.10\textwidth,width=0.10\textwidth]{example-image-a} }
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[height=0.10\textwidth,width=0.10\textwidth]{example-image-b} }
\fancyhead[C]{ Course--XXX \\ University xxx\vspace{0.02\textwidth}}
\fancyfoot[L]{Course--XXX, year -- 2020}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page -- \thepage}
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt} % width of line bellow the header
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}

\newcommand{\borders}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node [anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt]
    at (current page.north west)
    {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style = {anchor=center}]
        \draw[%
        anchor=north,
        line width=2.pt, % width of the frame
        color=blue] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth-4pt,\paperheight-4pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}    

1. \kant[1]

\bigskip

a

b

c

d

e

f

g

\bigskip

Select the right option.

\bigskip    

Solution:

\clearpage


2. \kant[2]

\bigskip

a

b

c

d

e

f

g

\bigskip

Select the right option.

\bigskip    

Solution:
    
\end{document}
```

[image: nnn]